# Erro ao usar ALIAS no select

Tags: sql, oracle

No select abaixo, gostaria de usar o alias `novonome` na segunda coluna (instr).

```
select 
    substr(titulo, 1, 20) AS **novonome**,
    instr(**novonome**, ' ')+1
from conteudo;
```

Mas recebo o erro:

> ORA-00904: "novonome": identificador inválido

Answer (score 1):

Na real você tem dois problemas; o primeiro gera erro na execução pois o alias está definido entre dois asteriscos ao invés de entre aspas:

```
select substr(titulo, 1, 20) AS 'novonome' 
from conteudo;
```

O segundo é que não dá pra usar o valor retornado pelo alias como você pretende, teria de jogar a mesma chamada de função para retorno da segunda coluna:

```
select
  substr(titulo, 1, 20) AS 'novonome',
  instr(substr(titulo, 1, 20), ' ') + 1
from conteudo;
```